# domainname: command not found

Tags: unix, command-line

I am on a mac

I was learning Unix commands in a tutorial, then I saw someone typing `domainname` on the terminal. It works for him but it didn't work for me.

Here is my PATH environment variable: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/hamzabelmellouki/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

when I type domainname the output is `-bash: domainname: command not found`

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no widely used standard command or script called `domainname` that I know of; it's not a shell built-in, it's not a core utility, and POSIX doesn't know anything about it. They might have an alias, or a function, or a command somewhere on their machine.

Comment: the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/domainname
he was also on a mac. Yep! he did it on a mac. alias? well, I don't think so. I am sure I am missing something

Comment: I don't have this command on my Mac, and I don't see it in Homebrew. It seems to be part of [net-tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/). For Debian/Ubuntu, you should be able to get it from `apt install net-tools`.

Comment: There's also a [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools).

Comment: ok cool, but he wasn't using any Linux distribution. he was on a mac and he was able to play with these networking commands.

Comment: the tutorial: https://www.lynda.com/Mac-OS-tutorials/System-information-commands/78546/83648-4.html?autoplay=true

Comment: You can always download the source and compile it yourself.